# Jquery Dynamic fancy box

Tags: jquery

Loading fancybox from Jquery how can I retrieve the contents of a div ID on a page and not the whole page. This is my code so fare which gets me the whole page:

The index view(this links to the show view of styel):

```
<div class="style_image"> <%=link_to (image_tag style.cover.pic.url(:normal)), style %></div>
```

The show view (I want to to appear in the fancybox):

```
<div id="show_style">

    ALL THE CONTENT!

</div>
```

application.js:

```
$(function() {

$(".style_image a").live('click', function(event) { 

    $(".style_image a").fancybox();
    return false;       

});
});
```

I have also tried the following with no success:

```
$(function() {

$(".style_image a").live('click', function(event) { 

    $(".style_image a" + "#show_style").fancybox();
    return false;       

});
});
```

I'm not sure how this is done as there is little info on the [fancy box docs](http://fancybox.net/howto).
I wish this to be done dynamically not inline.

Comment: Wait, do you want the anchor that has an id of "show_style"?

Comment: I want to get the content of the ID show_style from the href and display it in the FAncyBox!

Comment: Ok...I think the names you are using for everything is confusing me, and possibly everyone else. When you say "I want to get the content of the ID show_style" does that mean the content of the element with the id of show_style? And when you say "from the href" are you talking about the content of the anchor element? or the actual href data.... Please be more specific about things or it will be hard to help. Can you please post your html for these elements...That would help.

Comment: I added some HTML to make the question more clear thanks for help!!

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem also .

now it has been solved.

here is the answer:

```
  function view(url){

     $.fancybox(
             url,
             {
                 type: 'iframe',
                 width            : '35%',
                 height            : '50%',
                 showCloseButton: true,
                 opacity: true,
                 overlayOpacity: 0,
                 transitionIn: 'none',
                 transitionOut: 'none',
                 enableEscapeButton: true
             }
     );
}




<a onclick="view('ViewFacility?rid=2');return false;" >click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I know what you mean, but if you want to call fancybox() on just the element clicked try this:

```
$(function() {

$(".style_image a").live('click', function(event) { 

    $('this').fancybox();
    return false;       

});
});
```

Comment: Peter this will only call the fancy box standardly pulling the href from the link(".style_image a"). I want to get only the #show_style ID from the href as described above.

Comment: I don't think I follow you. Is #show_style ID inside the anchor? Maybe you should show me some HTML...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based off of the newest information you provided I believe what you are trying to do is take all of the content from inside the show_style element and put it inside the fancybox. Here is the javascript.

```
$(function() {
    $("a#linkEle").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': true
    });
});
```

And your html will point to the content inside the show_style element

```
<a id="linkEle" href="#show_style"></a>
<div style="display:none"><div id="show_style">ALL CONTENT TO BE SHOWN</div></div>
```

See how the anchor href points to the div with an id of show_style. If you are trying to get all of the content from inside show_style and put it inside the fancy box, I believe this is how you would do that.

Metropolis

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Fancybox documentation](http://fancybox.net/howto), you'll want your `<a>` tag to have `#show_style` as their `href` element.

```
<div class="style_image"><a href="#show_style">Click here to show fancybox</a></div>
```

Then your first code should work:

```
$(function() {

$(".style_image a").live('click', function(event) { 

    $(".style_image a").fancybox();
    return false;       

});
});
```